# ReactJS production build with react-router not working

Tags: reactjs, deployment, react-router

I have created simple app with `react-router` which part looks like:

```
                    <BrowserRouter>
                      <Switch>
                        <Route
                            exact
                            path="/"
                            render={() => <Redirect to="/home" />}
                        />
                        {layoutRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
                          return (
                              <Route
                                  path={prop.path}
                                  component={prop.component}
                                  key={key}
                              />
                          );
                        })}
                      </Switch>
                    </BrowserRouter>
```

but when the app is build and deployed to the web server is rendered as a white page and not even redirecting to the `/home` component.

The app itself was created via `create-react-app` and `package.json` looks like:

```
{
  "name": "front-end",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": ".",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "formik": "^1.5.8",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "json-server": "^0.15.1"
  }
}
```

Any clue why is working on a development environment as `npm start` but not when build and deployed?

Comment: try to remove "homepage": "." from packages.json

Comment: @Satif  I have done that and it was even worse - not loading any static CSS or JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that helpful:

> If you’re using Apache HTTP Server, you need to create a `.htaccess`
>   file in the public folder that looks like this:
>
> ```
> Options -MultiViews
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
> ```
>
> It will get copied to the `build` folder when you run `npm run build`.